# Does the "filter" opacity option in CSS transfer to sub-elements?

Tags: html, templates, css

```
#box{
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}


<div id="box">
    <div id="goat">
    </div>
</div>
```

Will "goat" have an opacity of 50?

Comment: Is it just the `background` on `#box` that you want to be semi-transparent?

Comment: @thirtydot: Yes, I only want the background of the box to be transparent. nothing else. I don't want the text inside to be transprent. I don't want its children to be transparent.

Comment: Use an rgba value on the background and set your opacity value in the 'a' value of your color. Setting opacity rule in css sets the opacity for the element and all it's child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yep it will http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SxLe4/

Tested in IE9

Comment: How do I make it not go to sub elements? I only want THAT box to have opacity.

Comment: Nitpick: I suspect you mean you only want that box to obey your custom opacity setting. An element without opacity is invisible.

Comment: I would make two divs and position them over each other. Siblings instead of parent/child, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SxLe4/3/

Comment: Forgot to update my fiddle - here's the sibling example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SxLe4/4/

Answer (score 1):

> @thirtydot: Yes, I only want the
>   background of the box to be
>   transparent. nothing else. I don't
>   want the text inside to be transprent.
>   I don't want its children to be
>   transparent.

You could use:

```
#box {
    background: url(semi-transparent-matching-the-rgba.png);
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5)
}
```

- Browsers that support `rgba` will use the second `background` declaration with `rgba`.
- Browsers [that do not](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors) will ignore the second `background` declaration and use the `.png`.

For a solution that does not involve a `.png` image, see:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Splitting into two elements also works, but it's covered by the other answers here, so I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the double semiopacity and only apply it on the background, you can split it into two boxes.

**CSS**

```
#box {position: relative;}

#goat, #background {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#goat{z-index:1;}

#background {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="goat"></div>
    <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

This of course depends on your content and how